# Batch Import gpx tracks in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, import, gpx

I am trying to import multiple gpx tracks into QGIS using the plugin "Batch GPS Importer".  This has worked in the past but now gives me the error `Sorry, no valid GPX features found in the folder!`.

The source folder contains only .gpx files, all of which can be individually imported into QGIS without problem.

Is the plugin still working?

MacOS 12.3,
MacBookPro M1,
QGis 3.24.0

Comment: Just successfully tested this plugin on Windows OS with the same tracks I was trying to import on the Mac, and it works fine.  Looks like either an issue with Mac OS or M1 chipset

Comment: I think it is most likely a permission issue.